# What is the term for the "amuse-bouche" at the end of the meal?

Tags: language, restaurant

At several restaurants I've been to, in addition to  serving an amuse-bouche at the beginning of a meal, there is an equivalent complementary small desert served at the end, sometimes before or after the check.

What on earth is the name for this "course"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of "mignardises." This is what they call it on the french laundry menu, and others.

Another possibility is "Petit Fours", which are small pastries typically served at the end of a meal.  I believe there is some overlap in the use of the two terms.

Comment: mignardises is pretty commonly used on tasting menus and would actually include something like a petit fours so i think this is on the right track. +1

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard a specific name for this that is widely used.

In some places it might be called a a lagniappe (a small free extra, the term originated in Louisiana), or perhaps just a complimentary dessert.

Answer (score 1):

In traditional English formal meals, the final course after dessert would be a [savoury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savoury_(dish)) — a small, often strongly-flavoured dish such as welsh rarebit or angels on horseback, to ‘clear the palate’ before the port or other digestif.

(As the name indicates, this would *not* be a sweet dish, so depending what OP means by ‘desert’ [sic], this may not apply.)

Answer (score 0):

If seeking an English language term, I think "Post-Prandial" is a could work well. But I cannot claim that it's ever been used before.

Comment: "post-prandial" is a medical/nutrition term, it doesn't get used in a kitchen/dining setting.

Comment: So... let's use words from other languages that no one knows what they mean, so we can sound super-sophisticated?  Food is medicine. Seriously, "post-prandial" is fine. 

Save "mignardises" for the French bistro.

Comment: @rumtscho I disagree. It's fusty and will likely come across as affected, but I've heard (well, read) it used in this context, generally when talking about liqueurs.

Comment: @rumtscho I am familiar with the term "post-prandial" as a way of describing after dinner cocktails.

Comment: "Postprandial" literally means "after a meal", and with no further qualifications would be assumed to refer to a postprandial drink (digestif).  I've never heard it used for a part of the meal, and definitionally that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @All:  as I am a bartender, the term "post-prandial" makes good sense to me. That culinary/foodie-types do not wish to use the term for a "bite" does make linguistical sense.  Still, I would continue to argue that bites and swallows are equivalent and, therefore, do not require separate terminology. 

But I do th ank you all for your replies and for helping educate me about the terminology you know and are willing to share.  

This does mean a lot to me!

[ps. Tried to fix the spelling error on dessert, above, but was shut down for not having enough "cred".]